# Searching with meteor autocomplete package (mizzao)

Tags: javascript, meteor, autocomplete

I am new to Javascript and Meteor and having some trouble getting the Meteor autocomplete package from Mizzau to work correctly.   I can get the form to autocomplete just fine, but having trouble getting it to filter my todos.  The end result I am hoping for is to enter in a todo into the autocomplete and have it filter the subscription, I would also settle for search and going from there.  I will also say my initial state is the list returns 0 todos (none are displayed)   I feel like I may be close.   A good part of my code came from this: [Meteor - autocomplete with "distinct" feature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30027668/meteor-autocomplete-with-distinct-feature)
T
Does it have something to do with my subscription?

Here is my server side publish call:

```
    Meteor.publish("todosAuto", function(selector, options) {
  Autocomplete.publishCursor(Todos.find(selector, options), this);
  this.ready();
});
```

My client side subscription:

```
Meteor.subscribe('todosAuto');
```

The relevant part of my template:

```
<div class="container todoFormSec">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      {{> inputAutocomplete settings=settings id="msg" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..."}}
    </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5 pull-right">
      <h1 class="todocountstyle text-right">You Have {{ todoCount }} Todos</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="todos">
          {{ #each todosAuto }}
              {{ >todo }}
          {{ /each }}
      </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my settings:

```
Template.home.helpers({

  todos: function() {
  return Todos.find();
},


todoCount: function() {
  return Todos.find({userid: Meteor.userId()}).count();
},

  settings: function() {
    return {
      position: "top",
      limit: 5,
      rules: [
        {
          token: '@',
          collection: 'Todos',
          field: "title",
          subscription: 'todosAuto',
          template: Template.titlePill
        },
        {
          token: '#',
          collection: 'Todos',
          field: "categories",
          options: '',
          subscription: 'todosAuto',
          matchAll: true,
          template: Template.dataPiece
        }
      ]
    };
  }

});

Template.home.events({ // listen for selection and subscribe
  "autocompleteselect input": function(event, template, doc) {

   Meteor.subscribe("todosAuto", doc.title);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the past I tried to use this autocomplete package you are having trouble with. I found it just wasn't high fidelity enough for my needs. Therefore I recommend `Twitter typeahead` and `bloodhound` to you. I am very happy with the following packages [ajduke:bootstrap-tokenfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26760419/use-meteor-collections-for-typeahead-bloodhound-preferably-without-making-my-ow) in combination with [sergeyt:typeahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26760419/use-meteor-collections-for-typeahead-bloodhound-preferably-without-making-my-ow)

The time investment is well worth it. See my [previous posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26760419/use-meteor-collections-for-typeahead-bloodhound-preferably-without-making-my-ow) for examples. [Here](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/) are more examples.

If the above is too complicated, try [jeremy:selectize](https://github.com/jshimko/meteor-selectize). Point is that there are plenty of better packages out there.

Comment: I was hoping to get an answer in the spirit of what I was asking, but ill go ahead and accept your answer.